# RGB Terminal Colors with Haskell and Brick

Tags: haskell, terminal, rgb, tui, haskell-brick

I know that the [Brick](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/brick) and the [VTY](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vty) hackage do not support escape sequences. [VTY](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vty) only supports 240 colors.

Is there any workaround to use true RGB colors and not mess up the layout?

This is an example I made, but I can't get the border right:

```hs
module BrickTest where

import Brick                (simpleMain, Widget, str)
import Brick.Widgets.Border (border)
import Text.Printf          (printf)

main :: IO ()
main = simpleMain $ colorWidget (255, 0, 0)

type RGB = (Int, Int, Int)

colorWidget :: RGB -> Widget ()
colorWidget (r, g, b) = border $ str (prefix ++ "a" ++ postfix)
    where
        prefix = printf "\ESC[38;2;%d;%d;%dm" r g b
        postfix = "\ESC[0m"
```

output:

```
┌──────────────────┐
│a│
└──────────────────┘
```

[image: terminal screenshot]

Comment: Brick supports ANSI terminal escape codes, and Vty as well: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vty-5.29/docs/Graphics-Vty-Attributes-Color.html#t:Color (this is used in Brick with https://hackage.haskell.org/package/brick-0.55/docs/Brick-Themes.html#t:CustomAttr). The ISO colors are used exactly to get rid of the programmer specifying ANSI terminal escape sequences themselves.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem but only 240 colors are supported and not 256^3 colors, which is supported by most modern terminal applications.

Comment: When you can add your own escape codes, you can tell the terminal to do whatever it supports.

Comment: @Carl escape codes can be inserted, but it always messes up the layout. Because the mentioned hackages do not support escape sequences. That's why I try to find a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround. I managed to implement a function `zeroWidthStr` that can print any string, and Brick handles it as if it has width 0. But I can't really explain how this is working internally, and it might have some other side effects.

```
module BrickTest where

import           Brick                       (Widget, raw, simpleMain, str,
                                              (<+>))
import           Brick.Widgets.Border        (border)
import           Data.List                   (intercalate)
import           Data.Text.Lazy              (pack)
import           Graphics.Vty                (defAttr)
import           Graphics.Vty.Image.Internal (Image (HorizText))
import           Text.Printf                 (printf)

main :: IO ()
main = simpleMain $ colorWidget (255, 0, 0)

type RGB = (Int, Int, Int)

colorWidget :: RGB -> Widget ()
colorWidget (r, g, b) = border $ prefix <+> str "a" <+> postfix
    where
        prefix = zeroWidthStr $ printf "\ESC[38;2;%d;%d;%dm" r g b
        postfix = zeroWidthStr $ "\ESC[0m"

zeroWidthStr :: String -> Widget ()
-- | workaround to print any string in terminal, and hackage Brick (vty) handles it as if it has width 0
zeroWidthStr str = raw image
    where
        image = HorizText defAttr (pack modStr) 0 0
        modStr = str ++ repeatN "\ESC\ESCa" (length str)
        repeatN :: String -> Int -> String
        repeatN str n = intercalate "" $ take n $ repeat str
```

output:

[image: terminal screenshot]

Comment: I think you can use `raw` with `HorizText`, but instead of this `modStr` stuff, use `HorizText defAttr (pack str) outputWidth charWidth` where `str` contains the escape sequences, but `outputWidth` and `charWidth` are computed from `str` with the escape sequences *stripped*, using e.g. `stripEscapes = Graphics.Vty.Image.safe_wcswidth . Data.Text.unpack . Data.String.AnsiEscapeCodes.Strip.Text.stripAnsiEscapeCodes . Data.Text.pack`. Note `charWidth` should be ≥1. I think that’s more semantically appropriate too, as all you’re really doing is setting the display width per the visible chars.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `safe_wcswidth . stripEscapes` where `stripEscapes = …`

Comment: @JonPurdy do you mean like this? `outputWidth = stripEscapes str; charWidth = outputWidth; stripEscapes = safeWcswidth . unpack . stripAnsiEscapeCodes . pack`

Comment: I mean `stripEscapes = unpack . stripAnsiEscapeCodes . pack` (or you could add a version that doesn’t have to go through `Text`) and `outputWidth = safe_wcswidth (stripEscapes str)`. But of course you could have the function both strip the escapes and compute the width, and just call it something else, like `getOutputWidth`.